# Behaviour of libssh2_channel_write when channel is not blocking

Tags: c, sockets, nonblocking, libssh2

From `libssh2_channel_write_ex` man page:

> Actual number of bytes written or
>   negative on failure. 
>   LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN when it would
>   otherwise  block. While 
>   LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN is a negative
>   number, it isn't really a failure per
>   se.

Now I have a problem with that. When I receive `LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN` does it mean that nothing was sent and that I must resend all data? Or does it mean that some data have been sent

My problem is that if I'm trying to send more data that the underlying socket can hold, `write()` should block anyway, henceforth how can I hope to send a big block of data without getting `LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN` every time?

Comment: Can you use `SO_SNDBUF` with `setsockopt(2)` on the socket before trying to send huge chunks of data?

Comment: @sarnold: Actually I'm not trying to send huge chunks of data, but I'm sending data on several open channels at once. Do you mean I should ensure that the sum of all channel buffers sizes should be less than the underlying socket buffer size ?

Comment: I _think_ you ought to just get a short-write if you try to overstuff a kernel sending buffer (i.e., `write(2)` will return a value less than the length of the buffer you passed), so it should all "just work", if you've written your code to prepare for potential short writes. But I've never used the libssh2 library before, and I'm not confident enough to say what it _will_ do. :) I just thought if you knew the largest block you were ever going to send was 32k, then make sure the buffer is large enough to handle it in one `write(2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN means nothing was sent and you must send it all again. If *something* was sent, that number would be returned instead.

Answer (score 3):

LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN Will occur if no data has been sent which you have it in buffer. You Can send it again after Checking whether the socket is alive by using Select().
If Select() returns the event, you handle it appropriately and you can resend it.

Loop goes like this

```
    do
    {
     While (rc = libssh2_Channel_write_ex () == LIBSSH2_ERROR_AGAIN )
     {
      if(!select()) // Wait for timeout
        //Timeout
     }
     if(rc>0)
      //Read next set of data into buffer for sending
     else if(rc <0)
      // Libssh2 error
    }
```